# Not able to open the localhost 8080 to add bika to the browser

Tags: plone

I have followed steps to install bika LIMS.
https://github.com/bikalabs/bika.lims/wiki/Bika-LIMS-Installation#windows-installation-steps

I am not able to complete the installation as localhost:8080 is not loading any page. It is taking forever to load. What might be the reason for this? For the reference, I am getting this on the command prompt.

```
C:\Plone43>bin\instance fg
2016-08-09 18:08:21 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Tue Aug 09 18:08:21 2016
        Hostname: Prognosys-lap
        Port: 8080
2016-08-09 18:09:33 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage ClientStorage (pid=492) created RW/normal for storage: '1'
2016-08-09 18:09:33 INFO ZODB.blob (492) Blob directory `C:\Plone43/var/blobstorage` is unused and has no layout marker set. Selected `
bushy` layout.
2016-08-09 18:09:33 WARNING ZODB.blob (492) Blob dir C:\Plone43\var\blobstorage\ has insecure mode setting
2016-08-09 18:09:33 INFO ZEO.cache created temporary cache file 'c:\\users\\misha\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp1t4k4s'
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you paste above from the command prompt indicates that Plone is running properly in the foreground and has connected to the database.  That you see no further output indicates that the requests you are making in the browser are not getting seen by the Zope client process

I suspect that you may have a firewall or other security setting in Windows that is preventing connecting to port 8080.  A request that never loads, but only spins forever can often be a symptom of this type of problem.

Check for firewall or other security settings in Windows that might prevent opening a connection to port 8080, and update the settings to allow these connections.

Comment: I used netstat -ano | findstr 8080 and I can see connection is established to PID 1184 and in the task manager it is showing python.exe process is running with PID 1184. I have ego secure security in my laptop. Is this affecting anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your Plone is configured to accept requests only for (the IP associated with the name) `Prognosys-lap`. 
Please see if you get something under `http://Prognosys-lap:8080`.

(On Unix systems, it's quite common to put `0.0.0.0` as the desired hostname/IP, which means "all network interfaces", in which case `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` would work as well.)